# What are cost-effective uses of gems?

Tags: clash-royale

I am a new player with about 214 gems and 183 gold in Clash Royale. The game states:

> Gems can be used to buy gold or to speed up unlocking chests.

when tapping the gem icon. Should I use the gems to unlock the chests, buy gold, or buy other chests (if so, which type of chest)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a free-to-play player, there are two main things you can do with your gems to conserve it; make it last longer:

- Speed up chests that are nearly completed, not those that have just started.
  *Alternatively, don't use them at all. You should be trying to save it for when cards begin to climb in costs (1,000 Gold at Level 8 to 9) and then [see below]:*

Or, to get the most out of it:

- Spend your gems only on gold.
  *Alternatively, wait until you have 500 Gems and buy the 10,000 Gold pack, and don't buy cards from the store. It is a known fact that you get **more** cards than gold.*
- Never spend your gems on purchasing chests from the store. It's not worth it.
  *That is, unless you're trying to get guaranteed Epics or Legendary cards, which you shouldn't be doing until most of your cards are maxed as the cards and gold values don't add up, even without the gem prices scaling with your Arena number.

  One exception to this are the occasional Epic Chest (using gold) and Legendary Chest (500 gems), which are much more profitable than other chests available for gems, or cards for gold.*

Comment: I don't get the last part. What do you mean by gold values not adding up?

Comment: For example, a Magic Chest is 320 Gems at Arena 1, which isn't worth the 1 Epic (2,000G), 6 Rares (about 500G), 23 Commons (about 250G) and 200-250 Gold you're getting. | 3,000G is worth ~180 Gems and the wait cost is 72 Gems, which totals to about 252 Gems. Meaning, you're better off buying gold and then use that gold to purchase cards from the shop in rotation. It may take time, but trust me: It won't *kill* your wallet.

Comment: @aytimothy As soon as you buy a chest it's unlocked. It says so on them in the store.

Comment: @ИвоНедев He doesn't mention anything about needing to unlock them.

Comment: @ИвоНедев When I said "and the wait cost is 72 Gems", I meant the unlock cost would be 72 gems if you were to get it through the drop cycle. I've included it in the calculation because shop chests prices are based on that the fact you bought the chest *and* gemmed it.